# Every subgroup of $(\mathbb {Z_n},+)$ is closed under multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I am stuck in this proof that every subgroup of $(\mathbb {Z_n},+)$ is also a subring. which requires me to prove it is closed under multiplication. I have to show if $a,b \in G<\mathbb {Z_n}$ , then $ab \in G<\mathbb {Z_n}$

Comment: I suggest starting with describing what the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ are.  This problem will be much easier if you describe what $G$ looks like.

Comment: Integer multiplication can be modeled as repeated addition, i.e. 5a = a+a+a+a+a.

Comment: Getting stuck is not too hard - what did you try? I would suggest induction on $b$, and prove that $G$ is closed under multiplication by every natural number.

Comment: @JohnMcGee thanks. So $ab \in G$ because $ab = b+b+...a times \in G$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\Bbb Z_n,+)$ is a cyclic group, and any subgroup $G$ is likewise cyclic. This means, in particular, that if $a,b \in G$, that:

$a = kg = g + g +\cdots + g\ (k$ times)

$b = mg = g + g + \cdots + g\ (m$ times)

for some integers $k,m$ and a generator $g$ of $G$.

Now compute $ab$ (mod $n$) -can you think of a way to somehow use the distributive law for integers, and then reduce mod $n$?

Comment: $ab=(km)g$, correct?

Comment: Yes, but you should be able to prove this (induction will work, but arguing from integers and reducing mod $n$ is "faster").

Comment: is $g = gcd(a,b)?$

Answer (score 0):

If you know about rings, then that should be easy to prove:

- Every additive subgroup of $\mathbb Z$ is in fact an ideal.
- The additive subgroups of $\mathbb Z/n$ correspond to the additive subgroup of $\mathbb Z$ that contain $n\mathbb Z$.
- So, every additive subgroup of $\mathbb Z/n$ is in fact an ideal, and hence closed under multiplication.